# Touchscreen and HDMI with FKMS

Tags: pi-4

I want to use a touch screen and an HDMI without X11.

If I use legacy GL mode, I can have two *display* outputs. One DSI and one HDMI.

But when I use FKMS, I don't have two outputs.

When I use legacy mode, everything is fine,
command `ls /dev/fb*` shows two framebuffers.

But if I add `dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d` to config, HDMI doesn't work and
command `ls /dev/fb*` shows one framebuffer.

I have two applications, each of which I want to see in one output. It means one is using DSI and the other is using HDMI.

I don't want to use legacy mode.

I want to use FKMS but I have the above problem.

I need two framebuffers but FKMS didn't add two framebuffers.